# I want to get my value from json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i have json like this

```
{
  "id":"1",
  "name":"Kitchen Set",
  "parent_id":"0",
 }, 
 {
  "id":"2",
  "name":"Bedroom",
  "parent_id":"0"
 }, 
 {
  "id":"3",
  "name":"Living Room",
  "parent_id":"0"
 }, 
 {
  "id":"4",
  "name":"Kitchen Set",
  "parent_id":"1",
  "price":"1000"
 }, 
 {
  "id":"5",
  "name":"Meja Bar",
  "parent_id":"1",
  "price":"2000"
 },
```

and i want to add `price:` to my javascript

here is my question i want to get the `price` from my json to my javascript how can i do that??

i try this but it doesnt work

```js
load_json_data('Price');

 function load_json_data(price)
 {
  var html_code = '';
  $.getJSON('int_fur_fin.json', function(data)
 }
```

and this is my javascript

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 load_json_data('Interior');

 function load_json_data(id, parent_id)
 {
  var html_code = '';
  $.getJSON('int_fur_fin.json', function(data){

   html_code += '<option value="">Select '+id+'</option>';
   $.each(data, function(key, value){
    if(id == 'Interior')
    {
     if(value.parent_id == '0')
     {
      html_code += '<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.name+'</option>';
     }
    }
    else
    {
     if(value.parent_id == parent_id)
     {
      html_code += '<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.name+'</option>';
     }
    }
   });
   $('#'+id).html(html_code);
  });

 }

 $(document).on('change', '#Interior', function(){
  var Interior_id = $(this).val();
  if(Interior_id != '')
  {
   load_json_data('Furniture', Interior_id);
  }
  else
  {
   $('#Furniture').html('<option value="">Select Furniture</option>');
  }
 });
    });

</script>
```

i use this javascript code to populate my dropdown

```
<form>
   <select name="Interior Details" id="Interior" class="form-control input-lg">
    <option value="">Select Interior Details</option>
   </select>
   <br />
   <select name="Furniture" id="Furniture" class="form-control input-lg" required >
    <option value="">Select Furniture</option>
   </select>
</form>
```

Comment: There are 5 objects, which price do you want

Comment: @Sajeetharan i want to get price form `parent_id : 1 `

Comment: The JSON shown is not valid, because you need to have a single object or array at the top level. Is that supposed to be an array of similar objects?

Comment: @nnnnnn yeah this json doesnt complete i use json to populate my dropdown

Comment: Maybe this [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/9ohzcn7c/)  will help. I had created this before seeing your updates. This will append new `options` to the `selects` based on the `id` of select to the `parent_id` in the `JSON`. It will also check if `price` exists before adding the `data-price` attribute but that's done for the sake of the demo. I'm sure you can add/edit/expand from the demo to make it fit your purpose. **Edit:** Comments within source code added.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[`array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)** method to find the matching element. Also i have **`modified`** your **`JSON`** as a array.

```
items.find(t=>t.parent_id ==='1');
```

**DEMO**

```js
var items = [{
  "id":"1",
  "name":"Kitchen Set",
  "parent_id":"0",
 }, 
 {
  "id":"2",
  "name":"Bedroom",
  "parent_id":"0"
 }, 
 {
  "id":"3",
  "name":"Living Room",
  "parent_id":"0"
 }, 
 {
  "id":"4",
  "name":"Kitchen Set",
  "parent_id":"1",
  "price":"1000"
 }, 
 {
  "id":"5",
  "name":"Meja Bar",
  "parent_id":"1",
  "price":"2000"
 }]; 
 
 var result = items.find(t=>t.parent_id ==='1');
 console.log(result);
```

**EDIT**

If you want multiple elements with matching id use **[`array.filter.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)**

```js
var items = [{
  "id":"1",
  "name":"Kitchen Set",
  "parent_id":"0",
 }, 
 {
  "id":"2",
  "name":"Bedroom",
  "parent_id":"0"
 }, 
 {
  "id":"3",
  "name":"Living Room",
  "parent_id":"0"
 }, 
 {
  "id":"4",
  "name":"Kitchen Set",
  "parent_id":"1",
  "price":"1000"
 }, 
 {
  "id":"5",
  "name":"Meja Bar",
  "parent_id":"1",
  "price":"2000"
 }]; 
 
 var result = items.filter(t=>t.parent_id ==='1');
 console.log(result);
```

Comment: But this contains **2** items with `"parent_id": "1"` but in your example only one is logged in the console.

Comment: i dont know , i thinks it will be not working if i use 21 different id

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: @ShevaAthalla Maybe this [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/bzvoLgvb/) might also be helpful. A slight change to **Sajeetharan**'s answer to show how to access the price/name property.

Comment: i use this json to populate my dropdown

Comment: @ShevaAthalla You haven't shown this `dropdown` or explained how you use it to populate anything. Please update your question with the relevant source code otherwise it's impossible to give you a solid answer.